# Locate WordPress custom menu table in phpmyadmin 5.6

Tags: phpmyadmin

Where is WordPress custom menu table located in `phpmyadmin 5.6`

I deleted a wp custom menu item and would like to restore in in `phpmyadmin 5.6`

Answer (score 0):

Once deleted in mysql, with any tool like phpmyadmin, is deleted forever.
I hope you have a backup

Comment: I deleted the navigation menu item in wordpress admin not mysql.